# Google chart not draw

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, charts, google-visualization

I have a one question. google chart not draw.

Here is my code

```
<script>
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "/temhum",
            dataType:"json",
        }).done(function (jsonData) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  console.log(jsonData);
  data.addColumn('string', 'date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
  data.addColumn('number', 'humidity');

  jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
    data.addRow([
      row.date,
      row.temperature,
      row.humidity
    ]);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    width: 600,
    height: 600
  });
}).fail(function (jq, text, err) {
  console.log(text + ' - ' + err);
});

  }

</script>
```

Here is my console log
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r18qF.png)

I don't know. why not draw chart. Does anybody know how to represent the data on real-time using node.js, google chart, and mysql?

Comment: You may use `drawChart()` before declaration.  Try to change 
 order as `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {...}  => ` to         function drawChart() {...}; google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

Comment: The same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the values in the json must match the column types

all three json columns come across as strings,
you can use the following to convert each to the correct type...

```
data.addRow([
  new Date(row.date),
  parseFloat(row.temperature),
  parseFloat(row.humidity)
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you. I solved problem

Solution is ..

sungyong & WhiteHat Code Mix

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script>
      google.load("visualization", "1", {
         packages: ["corechart"]
      });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
         var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "/temhum",
            dataType: "json",
         }).done(function(jsonData) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
            console.log(jsonData);
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
            data.addColumn('number', 'humidity');
            console.log(data);
            jsonData.forEach(function(row) {
               data.addRow([
                  new Date(row.date),
                  parseFloat(row.temperature),
                  parseFloat(row.humidity)
               ]);
            });
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
            chart.draw(data, {
               width: 600,
               height: 600
            });
         }).fail(function(jq, text, err) {
            console.log(text + ' - ' + err);
         });
      }
   </script>
```